# Add font awesome paypal icon to paypal code

Tags: html, paypal, font-awesome

I am trying to see if I can add the font awesome paypal icon `<i class="fa fa-paypal" ></i>` in front of the **PAY WITH PAYPAL** on my button.

http://dagrafixdesigns.com/2019/industrial-darker/graphics.html

Much like it is done on this page with the shopping cart icon `<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>.`

http://dagrafixdesigns.com/2017/industrial-darker/shop-details.html

However since this paypal code is specific to my account I cant get it to work so far, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
Dean

Comment: The PayPal button is an `<input>` element, which is not allowed to contain other elements (like `<i>`). Your best bet might be to make a PNG icon and set it as a `background-image` to the button, then position it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the element to a button and then styling it different to match what you had on your input would work.

```
<button class="btn-outline btn" type="submit" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>Pay With Paypal</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @dsadnick, your answer was pretty simple as I had the css in place, so it was a easy fix....

Answer (score 2):

Ideally using `<button>` tag would be best, but applied with an `input` something like this could work (adjust values as desired):

```css
input {
 height: 50px;
 width: 160px;
 background: none;
 border: 4px solid gray;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-indent: 20px;
}

.fa.fa-paypal {
 position: absolute;
 line-height: 50px;
 left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-paypal" id="botonsearch"></i>
<input type="button" value="pay with paypal" />
```

Comment: Thx @Syden  Your answer was really close to the above answer, and just a bit more work on my end to achieve the same goal...I appreciate your time on this and the code snippet...a huge thank you!!